# Calling reshape on an LSTMStateTuple turns it into a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I was using dynamic_rnn with an LSTMCell, which put out an LSTMStateTuple containing the inner state. Calling reshape on this object (by my mistake) results in a tensor without causing any error at graph creation. I didn't get any error at runtime when feeding input through the graph, either.

Code:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(size, state_is_tuple=True, ...)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, ...)
print(states) # state is an LSTMStateTuple
states = tf.reshape(states, [-1, size])
print(states) # state is a tensor of shape [?, size]
```

Is this a bug (I ask because it's not documented anywhere)? What is the reshaped tensor holding?

Answer (score 0):

I have conducted a similar experiment which may gives you some hints:

```
>>> s = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> t = tf.constant([[4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],                                                             
                     [6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]])
>>> g = tf.reshape((s, t), [-1, 3]) # <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_1:0' shape=(8, 3) dtype=int32>
>>> sess.run(g)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

We can see that it just concatenates the two tensors in the first dimension and performs the reshaping. Since the LSTMStateTuple is like a namedtuple then it has the same effect as tuple and I think this is also what happens in your case.

Let's go further,

```
>>> st = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(s, t)
>>> gg = tf.reshape(st, [-1, 3])
>>> sess.run(gg)
    array([[0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2],
           [3, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 4],
           [5, 5, 5],
           [6, 6, 6],
           [7, 7, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

We can see that if we create a LSTMStateTuple, the result verifies our assumption.